# How to get the start and end of an hour from a datetime in KQL?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In ADX (Kusto), given a datetime value, how can I get the start and end of the hour?

**Input**: `datetime(2023-07-21 12:11:10)`

**Expected output**:

start: `datetime(2023-07-21 12:00:00)`
end: `datetime(2023-07-21 12:59:59)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [make_datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-datetimefunction), you can [define the following functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-alter-function):

```
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = "Start of hour") startofhour(dt:datetime) {
    make_datetime(datetime_part('Year', dt), datetime_part('Month', dt), datetime_part('Day', dt), datetime_part('Hour', dt), 0, 0)
}
```

```
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = "End of hour") endofhour(dt:datetime) {
    make_datetime(datetime_part('Year', dt), datetime_part('Month', dt), datetime_part('Day', dt), datetime_part('Hour', dt), 59, 59.9999999)
}
```

which is executable like so:

```
print startofhour(datetime(2023-07-21 12:11:10)), endofhour(datetime(2023-07-21 12:11:10))
```

and the result is:

| print_0 | print_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-21T12:00:00Z | 2023-07-21T12:59:59Z |

Answer (score 1):

another option is using the [`bin()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction):

```
.create-or-alter function start_of_hour(dt: datetime)
{
     bin(dt, 1h)
}
```

```
.create-or-alter function end_of_hour(dt: datetime)
{
     start_of_hour(dt) + 1h - 1tick
}
```

```
print
    start = start_of_hour(datetime(2023-07-21 12:11:10)),
    end = end_of_hour(datetime(2023-07-21 12:11:10))
```

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-21 12:00:00.0000000 | 2023-07-21 12:59:59.9999999 |